# Issues with string and .String() in Golang

Tags: string, interface, go

I can't understand the following behaviour in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Something string

func (a *Something) String() string {
  return "Bye"
}

func main() {
  a := Something("Hello")

  fmt.Printf("%s\n", a)
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", a.String())
}
```

Will output:

```
Hello
Bye
```

Somehow this feels kinda incosistent. Is this expected behaviour? 
Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `String()` is defined on the pointer but you're passing a value to `Printf`.

Either change it to:

```
func (Something) String() string {
    return "Bye"
}
```

or use

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", &a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments types are different. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Something string

func (a *Something) String() string {
    return "Bye"
}

func main() {
    a := Something("Hello")

    fmt.Printf("%T %s\n", a, a)
    fmt.Printf("%T %s\n", a.String(), a.String())
}
```

Output:

```
main.Something Hello
string Bye
```